# How to solve this missing dependency in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The goal is to reset a value, that is mutated inside of the function, if the props have changed to something that is different from the current value.

I am trying out react hooks and am still not confident how to solve this and if it can be solved.
While this seems to work as expected, I get a ESlint warning:

```
Warning:(62, 8) ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'value'. Either include it or 
remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)


function (info) {
  const initialValue = info.value;
  const [value, set_value] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialValue !== value) {
        set_value(initialValue);
    }
  }, [initialValue]);
  ...};
```

I can't add the `value` variable to the dependency array, because it will prevent the mutation.

I checked the react-hooks documentation and this thread here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15865

But am still not confident how to apply this knowledge to my case.

Comment: Quick fix would be to add `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` before the line that causes the issue.

Comment: well that would just hide the symptoms but not fix the issue

Comment: true, but sometimes you need for effect to fire only once and than you would put empty array for deps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `value` in `useEffect` scope, you can use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
function App({ value: initialValue }) {
  const [value, set_value] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    set_value((prevValue) =>
      initialValue !== prevValue ? initialValue : prevValue
    );
  }, [initialValue]);

  return <></>;
}
```